# Windows to Windows Mapped Drive?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-10, mappeddrive

I'm trying to work on a remote Windows Server 2012 from my Windows 10 home PC and was told they map drives pretty much like https://www.serverintellect.com/support/windowsserver/mappingdrive/ where you just do \1.2.3.4\c$ and enter your account info.  I gave 2 common IP addresses I use which were added to a list in the firewall.

1) Is this still a secure way? If not, what's better for them?

2) If it is still a secure way, why would it work from one IP and not the other?  Home cable internet doesn't work but an office WiFi with a dedicated fiber line does.

Please let me know what else you need to know as I know this isn't a lot to go on, but I'm not sure what is relevant here.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: `Is this still a secure way?` It was never a very secure way, but if using SMB3 and Windows Server 2016 probably not that bad. Windows Server 2012 doesn't use SMB3. `Home cable internet doesn't work` my guess would be the cable ISP is blocking insecure protocols.

Comment: In short: Don't do this. Use a VPN to connect to the remote network and establish the CIFS connection over the VPN.

Comment: +1 for it not being a good idea. If 1.2.3.4 is the public IP of the server, then office wifi may well be succeeding due to it being on the same network / there being rules in place to allow traffic over wifi to the server. Connecting from your random home internet would hopefully be blocked otherwise anyone could attempt to login to the server from anywhere in the world.

Comment: Thanks all. Got a VPN setup and feel a lot better about that.